# linebreak in URL placeholdit.imgix.net

Tags: url

Is there a way to add a line break in a URL?
https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150
I want the text that appears in this placehold to have line breaks is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `%0A` in the URL to have new line.

Example : https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Hello%0AWorld&w=350&h=150

Comment: What is the unescaped version of `%0A` for us using base64 format?